# Guardar un audio(wav) con la función synthesizeToFile() en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Quiero guardar un TTS en .wav con la función synthesizeToFile(), pero me es imposible.

Este es el código que intento hacer funcionar:

```
mTts.synthesizeToFile("hola",null,new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/sound.wav"),"record");
```

Pero en el log de Android Studio Me salta el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.synthesizeToFile(java.lang.CharSequence, android.os.Bundle, java.io.File, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                  at it.moondroid.chatbot.MainActivity$ResponseReceiver.onReceive(MainActivity.java:388)
                  at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.executePendingBroadcasts(LocalBroadcastManager.java:297)
                  at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.access$000(LocalBroadcastManager.java:46)
                  at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Os prometo que he intentado seguir tutoriales, pero no hay forma.
Como se podría hacer con API 21 o superior?
Podríais poner un ejemplo que me sirva de guía?

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda.

**Editado:**

Código de la instancia del objeto mTts:

```
    public class TTSManager {

    private TextToSpeech mTts = null;
    private boolean isLoaded = false;

    public void init(Context context) {
        try {
            mTts = new TextToSpeech(context, onInitListener);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private TextToSpeech.OnInitListener onInitListener = new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                Locale loc = new Locale ("es", "ES");
                int result = mTts.setLanguage(loc);
                isLoaded = true;

                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("error", "This Language is not supported");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("error", "Initialization Failed!");
            }
        }
    };

    public void shutDown() {
        mTts.shutdown();
    }

    public void addQueue(String text) {
        if (isLoaded)
            mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        else
            Log.e("error", "TTS Not Initialized");
    }

    public void initQueue(String text) {

        if (isLoaded)
            mTts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        else
            Log.e("error", "TTS Not Initialized");
    }



}
```

Comment: Has añadido los permisos en el manifest?

Comment: Hola! Si, están añadidos. <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

Comment: Puedes poner el código de la instancia del objeto mTts por favor

Comment: Acabo de añadirlo como edición al post. Por si sirve de algo, convierte bien de texto a voz. Y dicho código está en otra clase, a parte del típico MainActívity. Gracias por tu tiempo JeCuRo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mTts.synthesizeToFile("hola",null,new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/sound.wav"),"record");
```

debe estar dentro del metodo

> onInit(int status)

de tu clase `TTSManager`, si no te salta un nullPointerException o null reference.
Prueba esto:

```
@Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                Locale loc = new Locale ("es", "ES");
                int result = mTts.setLanguage(loc);
                mTts.synthesizeToFile("hola",null,new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/sound.wav"),"record");
                isLoaded = true;
                Log.d("done", "ok");
                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.d("error", "This Language is not supported");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("error", "Initialization Failed!");
            }
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y desde `MainActivity` o cualquier otra actividad :

```
TTSManager manager = new TTSManager();
manager.init(this);
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias JeCuRo! Resuelto! A veces uno se traba y no ve luz! ;)

Comment: Nada hombre!!! Feliz de poder ayudar :)

Answer (score 1):

Asegura antes de llamar esta linea:

```
mTts.synthesizeToFile("hola",null,new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/sound.wav"),"record");
```

llamar el método `init()`, debes realizar esto:

```
mTts.init(getApplicationContext());
mTts.synthesizeToFile("hola",null,new File("/mnt/sdcard/Download/sound.wav"),"record");
```

Te sugiero revises dentro del método init() si se esta causando un error al crear la instancia `TextToSpeech()` :

```
   try {
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(context, onInitListener);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); //Revisa en el LogCat si se esta reportando un problema.
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Elenasys! Me había hecho un lío! ;)

Comment: Que bien solucionaste tu problema! =) saludos!